# Watson Assistant throws away webhook parameters

Tags: javascript, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to get values from an API to a dialog node of Watson Assistant. Using the webhook option, the API call happens but the parameters i set are not used on the request.

[image: parameter from dialog node]

API code:

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await get('https://api.senior.com.br/' + req.query.link)
  console.log(result);
  res.json({result}) 
});
```

The request.url or the request.query.link returned is just '/', just when i make the call manually this variables have the parameter that I send.

Answer (score 1):

[IBM Watson Assistant invokes the defined webhook via http POST request](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks). Thus, there are no query parameters, only the payload in the request body. Thus, in your code you need to use `req.body` (request body) instead of `req.query` (query parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get the parameter link from "req.body.link" (u.u), I just don't know why it doesn't appears on "req.query.link".

Comment: see my answer for the reason, POST vs. GET